# using system.runtime.caching to cache list data

Tags: c#, caching

I am trying to get data from the cache

I have a source solution where I have added code to cache

```
        MemoryCache cache;
        object cachedObject;
        object webServiceResult;
        ListItemCollection collListItem = null;
        cache = new MemoryCache("SomeName");
        cachedObject = cache.Get(ProjectType);
        if (cachedObject == null)
        {
           //getting data here
            cache.Add(ProjectType, itemobtained, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));
        }
```

I built this solution and added the dll as reference to console application which will call this for every row in excel sheet

When I debugged this, the cachedObject always seems to be null.

Not sure why its not able to get from cache

Comment: downvoters, unless you comment on what needs to be improved, it really doesn't help to improvise the question

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you declare cache in method scope it is being destroyed after method call.

Create it as a static field and then use it in your method:

```
static MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache();
```